# Is star walking a metonymy of space walking?

Tags: metaphors, metonymy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYsz1hP0BFo

Is star walking a metonymy of space walking? In the lyrics, we see "star walking", but it doesn't make sense, so I was wondering if it was a metonymy like when we say I am drinking a cup of coffee instead of I am drinking coffee.

Comment: Are you asking for lyric interpretation or to check your use of the word "metonymy"?

Comment: I am wondering if it makes sense to say star walking and why.

Comment: It's a meaningless phrase. Even in the context of those lyrics it's anyone's guess.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no useful answer seems possible to me. Its a phrase invented by the song writer, with no significant previous use and not obviously metonymy.  So answers would be speculative lyric interpretation.